# PLY Lex and Yacc Issues

Tags: python, yacc, lex, ply

I'm having trouble using PLY. I've been reading the [documentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html) and decided to try out the examples. The lexing example worked perfectly but parsing I could not get to work. I also, looking at the docs, don't understand how you interface lex and yacc together to create a proper compiler. The parser only included the lexer's possible tokens and as far as I can tell nothing else.

I added a few things like colour (Colorama module) and slightly different messages but apart from that this is identical to the example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

### LEXICAL ANALYSIS ###


import ply.lex as lex

import colorama
colorama.init()

tokens = (
    "NUMBER",
    "PLUS",
    "MINUS",
    "MULTIPLY",
    "DIVIDE",
    "LBRACKET",
    "RBRACKET"
)


t_PLUS = r"\+"
t_MINUS = r"-"
t_MULTIPLY = r"\*"
t_DIVIDE = r"/"
t_LBRACKET = r"\("
t_RBRACKET = r"\)"

t_ignore = "\t\r "

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r"\d+"
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

def t_newline(t):
    r"\n+"
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

def t_COMMENT(t):
    r"\#.*"
    print "Comment:", t.value

def t_error(t):
    print colorama.Fore.RED + "\n\nLEXICAL ERROR: line", t.lexer.lineno, "and position", t.lexer.lexpos, "invalid token:", t.value.split("\n")[0] + colorama.Fore.RESET
    t.lexer.skip(len(t.value))


def mylex(inp):
    lexer = lex.lex()

    lexer.input(inp)


    for token in lexer:
        print "Token:", token
```

That works fine, but the parser, however, does not:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import ply.yacc as yacc

from langlex import tokens

def p_expression_plus(p):
    "expression : expression PLUS term"
    p[0] = p[1] + p[3]

def p_expression_minus(p):
    "expression : expression MINUS term"
    p[0] = p[1] - p[3]

def p_expression_term(p):
    "expression : term"
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_term_times(p):
    "term : term MULTIPLY factor"
    p[0] = p[1] * p[3]

def p_term_div(p):
    "term : term DIVIDE factor"
    p[0] = p[1] / p[3]

def p_term_factor(p):
    "term : factor"
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_factor_num(p):
    "factor : NUMBER"
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_factor_expr(p):
    "factor : LBRACKET expression RBRACKET"
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_error(p):
    print "Syntax error!"

parser = yacc.yacc()

while True:
    s = raw_input("calc > ")
    if not(s):
        continue
    result = parser.parse(s)
    print result
```

I get the following error when I try to run it:

```
calc > 5 + 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\lang\langyacc.py", line 49, in <module>
    result = parser.parse(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ply\yacc.py", line 265, in parse
    return self.parseopt_notrack(input,lexer,debug,tracking,tokenfunc)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ply\yacc.py", line 881, in parseopt_notrack
    lexer = lex.lexer
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lexer'
```

I'm a beginner to lex, yacc and compiler development in general and have no clue why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't built the lexer in your lexer file. You have it in the function `mylex()` but it doesn't actually get built.

Pull it out of the function.

```
lexer = lex.lex()

def mylex(inp):
    lexer.input(inp)
    # etc.
```

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple! Looking at the error message it kind of makes sense now. It was searching for a variable called `lexer` in my lexer file.

Comment: Well, actually it's a number of other things. When you use your parser, you haven't provided the lexer that it should use. So by default, it will use the last built lexer. If you want full control over the parser and lexer, you should always specify which lexer should be used. e.g., `parser.parse(s, lexer=lexer)`